# Json array column order

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, sorting

i have the following json:

```
{
"Header": {
    "MCC": "415",
    "FO": "0",
    "REGID": "5"
},
"Contacts": [
    {
        "NAME": "jocelyne",
        "MO": "70123456"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "eliane",
        "MO": "03123456"
    }
] }
```

and i'm parsing the json string into a datatable using this method:

object classes:

```
Public Class Data
Public Header As Header
Public Contacts As DataTable
End Class

<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract()>
Public Class Header
<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name:="MCC")>
Public MCC As Integer
<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name:="FO")>
Public FO As Integer
<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name:="REGID")>
Public RegId As Integer
End Class
```

.net functions:

```
    Dim data As New Data
    data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Data)(json)
    mcc = data.Header.MCC
    FO = data.Header.FO
    regid = data.Header.RegId
    contactsDT = data.Contacts
```

my problem is that the contacts array in the json is being parsed as a datatable in the same order as passed in the json... is there a way to change the order of the columns? what i mean is that if i got in the json let's say `mo` before `name` i need to get in the datatable `name` before `mo` all the time

is there a way to do that?